# How to perform a rotation of a structure, specifically throughout molecular dynamics or umbrella sampling simulations?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, intermolecular-forces, enhanced-sampling

I have a structure, as depicted in the figure, which is a part of a longer chain. The portion within the red circle is predominantly parallel. My objective is to rotate this part, aiming to orient the structures perpendicular to each other. I am interested in assessing the ease with which I can execute this rotation.

[image]

I tried to define a harmonic constrain to a dihedral or an angle, but it didn't rortate as I want.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried using PLUMED? I think that it should help you with this. I apologize for not having enough time to write an answer.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas I haven't used PLUMED before. Can u write more inforamtion when you have time?

Comment: A quick search of the PLUMED manual shows that you can define an angle between three atoms, or a dihedral between four atoms using [ANGLE](https://www.plumed.org/doc-v2.9/user-doc/html/_a_n_g_l_e.html) colvars. I have not used PLUMED before, but I understand that it has a pretty extensive tutorial and documentation available.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas. But I already mentioned in my question that I tried to define a dihedral or angle and It did't work as I want.

Comment: Can you explain how did you do it? Please include a detailed description of how did you do it, so that i would be able to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas. I select different angle for each portion and use force constant to increase the angle and try to rotate the structure for example one angle was 120 degree so my objective is to increase from 120 to more than 180 degree

Comment: What kind is your coordinate file? is it xyz/pdb? do you have the two molecules in two different files objects? `predominantly parallel` means that the atoms are on a plane?

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro. Two molecules are in the same file (pdb) as well there is a solvent. They are not on plane.

Comment: did you try `pymatgen`? you can rotate molecules objects

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro. I didn't try because I don't know it, but in general, can this program rotate the system with a selected parameter to identify the rotation is favorable or not ?